# Easiest way to find a string

Tags: c++11

ALL,

Is there a better way to do:

```
if( str.find( L"[abc]" ) == std::wstring::npos && str.find( L"abc" ) != std::wstring::npos )
```

I just feel that this is not optimal/elegant.

TIA!

Comment: @selbie, I want to find `abc` and I don't care about `[abc]`. So, no, I want to find only one.

Comment: If this string is `"Lorem ipsum [abc] lorem ipsum abc foo"`, do you still consider this a match?  Your code would ignore the second instance of `abc` after seeing the `[abc]`

Comment: @selbie, yes, it will be a match and I'd like to know where `abc` is.

Answer (score 1):

I can make it **optimal** and **correct**, but it will be a challenge to make it **"elegant"**.

My preference order for code design is always **correctness** first.  Then **maintainability**, followed by **optimized**.  **Elegant** code means nothing if it's doesn't meet the other three goals.

:)

To get **exactly** what you want, which is to find match a substring (`"abc"`) within a string, but ignore all the bracketed matches (`"[abc]"`), with the possibility of bracketed match and non-bracketed match exist - you'll need to call find within a loop.

The code below will match "abc" at:

- The beginning of the string: `pos == 0`
- The end of the string: `pos+pattern.size() == str.size()`
- Within the middle of the string, but without brackets: `(str[pos - 1] != '[') || (str[pos+pattern.size()] != ']')`

And then it loops until find reaches `npos` or is about to go past the end of the string.

```
wstring pattern = L"abc";
size_t pos = 0;
size_t start = 0;

while (start + pattern.size() <= str.size())
{
    pos = str.find(pattern, start);
    bool match = (pos != string::npos) &&
                 (
                     (pos == 0) || (pos+pattern.size() == str.size()) || (str[pos - 1] != '[') || (str[pos+pattern.size()] != ']')
                 );
    if (match)
    {
        cout << "match found at " << pos << endl;
        break;
    }
    start = (pos == wstring::npos) ? str.size() : pos +  pattern.size();
}
```

The alternative to get a more "elegant" solution might be to use a [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/). And I tried to prototype a regular expression that would match "abc", but not "[abc]", and found that to a challenge.  The resulting expression, if solved, would be have been long and hard to read.  Regex isn't exactly "fast" either (depends on your requirements).

Comment: does it cover the case of `[ abc ]` or `[ abc]`?

Comment: @Igor - Both of those strings would be considered matches in both the code I posted as well as the code you posted in your original question. If you have expectation that a string matching the pattern `[<whitespace>abc<whitepspace>]` is to be filtered out, that's an exercise I'll leave up to you.